# Check whether string contains substring (NON CASE SENSITIVE)

Tags: javascript, typescript, substring, match, angular8

I am writing a function in javascript that iterates an array of string messages, ie

```
['Hallo', 'I am listening', 'CaLling iT', 'haLLing']
```

Now I want to implement a function which can iterate through each element of that array and search for the same sub-strings. So far i searched `includes()` which returns case sensitive results, `match()` which is also not returning non-case-sensitive results.

I want a function that returns non-case-sensitive results. Like if I try to find **all** substring from the array. I should get the following results.

- `all`
- `aLl`
- `aLL`

But I can't find any solution

Comment: Use `toLowerCase()` first with `includes()` or regex with case-insensitive flag.

Comment: To use less lines in my code i used **toLowerCase()**. It works perfectly. Thanks @Walk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to know whether array contains required non case sensitive string **some** with **toLowerCase** may be good solution:

```js
const findStr = (arr, str) => arr.some(e => e.toLowerCase().search(str.toLowerCase()) !== -1)

const arr = ['Hallo', 'I am listening', 'CaLling iT', 'haLLing']

console.log(findStr(arr, 'CaLlI'))
console.log(findStr(arr, 'i AM Lis'))
console.log(findStr(arr, 'Ca1'))
```

You can also use find like this to get elements that satisfy the expression:

```js
    const findStr = (arr, str) => arr.find(e => e.toLowerCase().search(str.toLowerCase()) !== -1)

    const arr = ['Hallo', 'I am listening', 'CaLling iT', 'haLLing']

    console.log(findStr(arr, 'CaLlI'))
    console.log(findStr(arr, 'i AM Lis'))
    console.log(findStr(arr, 'Ca1'))
```

Or you can use findIndex to get index of the first element that satisfies it:

```js
    const findStr = (arr, str) => arr.findIndex(e => e.toLowerCase().search(str.toLowerCase()) !== -1)

    const arr = ['Hallo', 'I am listening', 'CaLling iT', 'haLLing']

    console.log(findStr(arr, 'CaLlI'))
    console.log(findStr(arr, 'i AM Lis'))
    console.log(findStr(arr, 'Ca1'))
```

To return array you can use map:

```js
const findStr = (arr, str) => arr.map(e => e.toLowerCase().search(str.toLowerCase()) !== -1)

    const arr = ['Hallo', 'I am listening', 'CaLling iT', 'haLLing']

    console.log(findStr(arr, 'CaLlI'))
    console.log(findStr(arr, 'i AM Lis'))
    console.log(findStr(arr, 'Ca1'))
```

Comment: Thank you. This works great in case of Non case sensitive substrings too!!

Comment: And you have 4 different ways to get exactly what you want from the array. If this answer is enough please mark it as correct by hitting the green check button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **i** in regular expression to make a search case insensitive

```
let found = str.match(/all/i);
```

Comment: It doesn't accept variables for search

Answer (score 0):

The RegExp constructor accepts variables :

```
let arr = ['Hallo', 'I am listening', 'CaLling iT', 'haLLing']

const findText = (text) => {
    return arr.map((elem) => {
        var regex = new RegExp(text, 'i')
        return elem.match(regex) ? elem.match(regex)[0] : null
    })
}

console.log(findText('all'));
```